# Best way to resize 3d to 2d matrix

Tags: deep-learning, embeddings

I have a `(5, 128, 768)` matrix, that is, I have 5 embedding spaces of shape `(128, 768)`. Since they all keep a relation, and for the sake of my model, I need to combine them into a unique output: `(1, 128, 768*5)`. If I just concat them all along `axis=-1`, will I be losing some info?

Making that concatenation is the only way I can think of solving this. Is there any better option?

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem. You have 5 embedding spaces of shape `(128, 768)`, which you store together in the tensor `(5, 128, 768)`. Now, my question is, why do you want to convert the tensor of shape `(5, 128, 768)` to `(1, 128, 768*5)`? You don't explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you want to resize and reduce your matrix size, you can use one of the dimension reduction techniques.

[Here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/08/dimensionality-reduction-techniques-python/) there is a link that may be helpful to you.

Comment: thank you for answering. By doing dim reduction, will I lose info?

Comment: techniques are different and in that link, it is written for every technique that is lossless or lossy decomposition.